# How to convert a svg source code retrieve from database and present it as an image in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I have a svg source code saved in MYSQL as a LONGTEXT. My server side will retrieve it and send it to front-end which i'm using Angular. How do my front-end render it into html?

Example of svg code saved in MYSQL would be like (i copied from some where just for example):

```
<svg height="210" width="500">   
<polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"/> 
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

The design for this svg is a star. When my front-end received this code, how does it present this code as a star in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers support rendering of SVG images. If you just print the SVG content on the page, it will work without a problem as if it were an IMG tag.

If you want to support legacy browsers, like IE8 or very old versions of the Android stock browser, you will need to convert the SVG image to another format like PNG. This should happen on the server side. There are tools like ImageMagick that you can use for that.